# Markaps in ImageView such as instagram have

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I need to create the markups on image view that should look like the markings Instagram. The client should click on some position on the image, enter some text and save it.
For now, the only solution that I see is :

1. Get click position in the onToch event.
2. Dynamically put some edit boxes to this position.
3. Save the text and coordinates.

However, I don't know yet how this will work on different screen sizes. 
Since I'm mostly web developer and definitely don't now all android capabilities I hope someone with experience will give me advice. Maybe there some widgets for this task, or algorithm for counting position?

[image]

Comment: My suggestion is that, you can do it by getting (x,y) coordinate of imageView, whenever you open the image you can get the actual size to (x,y) position and this is the best way to do it.

Comment: I think this would be helpful to you. https://github.com/imhemantsharma/InstagramTagFeature